# Menu Item position appeared incorrectly. How to arrange that?

Tags: android-layout, menu, optionmenu

[image: how to arrange menu item properly]

menu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/ref" 
  android:title="Refresh"
  android:icon="@drawable/refe"/>
<item android:id="@+id/ser"
    android:title="Search" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ser"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/loc"
    android:title="Location" 
    android:icon="@drawable/yourlo"/>
<item android:id="@+id/logout" 
    android:title="Logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/log"/>
```

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

how can i arrange this menu item properly. I am beginner to android. I tried to create menu item. I created but not in proper order. I don't know what to do for getting arranged menu.

Comment: show us some xml layout

Comment: codes updated.@developerCoder

Comment: if you want to make perfect layouts for your projects you should use photoshop and dimensions for your device. And actually you can change their positions by giving them padding.